# Angular 2+ using DI with instantiated models

Tags: javascript, angular

I'd like to be able to instantiate a model with a constructor, but still give that model injected services.

In other words, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
var book = new Book({ id: 5 });   // creates instance, sets id = 5
book.makeHttpCall();              // makes an API call with Angular's http service
```

To accomplish this, I have a "factory" that uses the standard dependency injection to fetch the `http` service.  This factory has a method, e.g. `make()` that creates an instance of the model.  Then it takes a reference to the `http` service it injected, and assigns it to a variable inside the model.

In code, using books as an example:

Service that uses this setup:

```
@Injectable()
export class LibraryService {
    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private bookFactory: BookFactory
    ) {}

    getBook(): Observable<BookModel> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/book/1')
            .map((res) => {
                return this.bookFactory.make(res.json().data)
            });
    }
}
```

Factory to create the models, and give them the `http` service:

```
@Injectable()
export class BookFactory {
    constructor(public http: Http) {}

    make(def): BookModel {
        let book = new BookModel(def);

        book.di = {
            http: this.http
        };

        return book;
    }
}
```

Book model that can now use the `http` service from `this.di.http`:

```
export class BookModel {
    di: any;
    constructor(private def: object) {}

    makeHttpCall() {
        this.di.http.get(...)
        ...
    }
}
```

What I have works.  But it seems extremely hacky.  As if I am doing something that is very against the "Angular way to do things".  In AngularJS (1.x), I accomplished this with normal Angular factories, and all was well.  But this seems to be the only way that I've seen to do this in Angular 2.

**Questions:**

1. **Is this strategy frowned upon?**  Is it not the "Angular way"?
2. **Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?**  I found some things such as `providers.useFactory` and `ReflectiveInjector`, but neither seemed to accomplish what I was looking for.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you don't do something bad in terms of angular but in terms of software design. It seems like you mix responsibilities. Shouldn't Book be a class that just holds a book data. A class that do api call should be some kind of repository pattern that gets ids or other data from book instance. Also check out s from [**S**olid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 1):

I interpret what you are doing as follows:

- You first have a page that loads Books from a remote server via http
  call
- Once you have your Book list in the app, then you may have the
  need to fetch further data for a specific Book querying again a remote server

If this is the case, than you have to build a service (e.g. `BookService`) with 2 methods:

- `getBookList(): Observable<Book[]>`
- `getDetailsForBook(book: Book): Observable<any>` (the type of the Observable returned by this method can be made more specific via specific typing, which depends on the app context)

`BookService` itself uses DI to get Angular `Http` client in the standard Angular way (i.e. referencing `Http` in its constructor).

BookService can be then configured in DI and provided to all Components (or Services) which need to use it.

I hope this is clear and can help.